# Slick Slider how to append pagination numbers to anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

Instead of having the numbers in Javascript, I want to have them in the HTML body:

```
    var slickOpts = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    //centerMode: true,
    easing: 'swing',
    speed: 700,
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    prevArrow: $('.prev'),
    nextArrow: $('.next'),
    customPaging: function(slick,index) {
        const allnumbers = $(".pagenumbers").append(index + 1); <--Not working
        //return '<a style="color: black">' + (index + 1) + '</a>';
        return allnumbers;
    }
  };
```

And here is the anchor tag in the HTML:

```
<a style="color:black;" class="pagenumbers"></a>
```

Right now, I am only getting 1 number instead of a total of 15. What am I doing wrong?